# Caching with Spring and ehcache doesnt work as expected

Tags: spring, caching, ehcache

I have a `Product` model object like this -

```
class ProductDTO {
    int id;
    String code;
    String description;

   //getters and setters go here
}
```

I am writing a service (code below) that looks up products by id or code and returns their description. I am using Spring 4 and ehcache to cache the results.

I have 2 methods - one for lookup by id and one for lookup by code - they are `getProductByCode` and `getProductById`. Both return the description as a string. They do so by calling `getAllProducts()` which returns a list of all products. The callers then search the list for a product matching the id or code and return the description.

`getAllProducts()` also calls 2 methods with `@CachePut` for each product - to save the description Strings in cache - by key `code` and `id`.

Caching works properly if the same arguments are passed for `code` or `id` to to the `getProductByCode` and `getProductById` methods. But if I pass a different argument, `getAllProducts()` is called again.

How do I achieve the desired behavior - where every time a call is made to `getAllProducts()`, all descriptions get cached and a subsequent call looks up the cache rather than going to the repository?

```
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {

    @Autowired
    ProductsRepository ProductRepo;

    @Override
    public List<ProductDTO> getAllProducts() {
        List<ProductDTO> products = ProductRepo.getAllProducts();
        for(ProductDTO prodDTO : products) {
            String desc = prodDTO.getDescription();
            String code = prodDTO.getCode();
            int id = prodDTO.getId();
            putDescriptionInCache(desc, code);
            putDescriptionInCache(desc, id);
        }
        return products;
    }

    @CachePut(value = "products", key = "#id")
    public String putDescriptionInCache(String description, int id){
        return description;
    }

    @CachePut(value = "products", key = "#code")
    public String putDescriptionInCache(String description, String code){
        return description;
    }

    @Override
    @Cacheable(value="products", key="#id")
    public String getProductById(Integer id) throws NullPointerException {
        String dtoDesc = null;
        List<ProductDTO> products = getAllProducts();
        for(ProductDTO currDTO : products) {
            int currId = currDTO.getId();
            if(id.equals(new Integer(currId))) {
                dtoDesc = currDTO.getDescription();
            }
        }
        return dtoDesc;
    }

    @Override
    @Cacheable(value="products", key="#code")
    public String getProductByCode(String code) throws NullPointerException {
        String dtoDesc = null;
        List<ProductDTO> products = getAllProducts();
        for(ProductDTO currDTO : products) {
            String currCode = currDTO.getCode();
            if(currCode.equals(code)) {
                dtoDesc = currDTO.getDescription();
            }
        }
        return dtoDesc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Caching is implemented using AOP. AOP is applied using proxies and thus only applies to method calls going into the object. Internal method calls don't pass through the proxy and as such those 2 method calls are basically futile.

Comment: Thanks M.Deinum. This information along with another post - (sorry I lost its link now) helped. I moved both putDescriptionInCache() methods to lower layer (inside ProductsRepository) and added following annotation to getProductByCode() and getProductById() - @Cacheable("products"). This way, the first call goes through getAllProducts() and caches the data. Also, my ProductRepository has a couple of other methods - getDirectionalTextById() and getDirectionalTextByCode() - each has SQL to get description. I call these from the same name methods one layer above.

Answer (score 1):

As it was commented by [M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum), the problem comes from the annotations, like `CachePut` or `Cacheable`, being transformed into an aspect at runtime. And the main limitation with that approach is that calls from the same class are not properly captured.

As you replied yourself in the comments section, moving the annotated methods to another type that is injected in the current one solves the problem.

Comment: Does this also apply to other annotations like @Cacheable?

Comment: Yes it does, edited the answer to make this more clear. Of course if annotations have another impact than having to decorate a method call, the remark is not relevant to those.